# Filter laravel eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have Groups, Users, GroupPositions, table.

**Relationship:**
Users belongsToMany Groups
Users belongsToMany GroupPositions
Group hasMany GroupPositions

```
//users
public function groupPositions() {
return $this->belongsToMany(
    'App\Models\GroupPositionView',
    'vw_group_members',
    'userId',
    'groupPositionId');
}

public function groups() {
return $this->belongsToMany(
    'App\Models\GroupView',
    'vw_group_members',
    'userId',
    'groupId');
}
```

I need to select a single group, with the members and their respective position in that particular group. A member can be part of different groups with DIFFERENT positions. He could be a leader in one group, or a manager in a different group.

Currently, I have this query:

```
$group = GroupView::where('tag', $tag)
->with(['user.groupPositions'])
->get();
```

It gives me ALL the positions of the member in all the group that he is a member of. I want to filter it to the specific group.

I also have this one:

```
$groupId = 1;
$group = GroupView::with(['users.groupPositions' => function($query) use($groupId) {
    $query->whereHas('group', function($query) use($groupId) {
        $query->where('groupId', $groupId);
    });
}])
->where('groupId', $groupId)
->firstOrFail();
```

This one works. However, the problem is that **I need to get the group via tag.** If I change all the groupId to tag, it does not work anymore. Probably because groupPositions and my vw_group_members does not have a tag column.

So my question is, is it possible to filter my query via tag?

Comment: what are the specific groups that you want to filter to ?

Comment: What do you mean? I only want to view the groups that the user is part then his position in that particular group.

Comment: I don't know whether the GroupPositions are unique per group, but if so, you can switch around the `with` in the first query?

`$group = GroupView::where('tag', $tag)
->with(['groupPositions.user'])
->get();`

This gets the grouppositions of the group and the the users belonging to them

Comment: @teun Thanks. That actually worked and is way more simple. I didn't thought of that.

Comment: @Jonathan Lightbringer I dont know whether youve noticed, but the bounty is still up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the GroupPositions are unique per group, you can switch around the `with` in the first query:

```
$group = GroupView::where('tag', $tag)
    ->with(['groupPositions.user'])
    ->get();
```

This gets the `groupPositions` of the group and the users belonging to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $group = GroupView::where('tag', $tag)->with(['groupPositions.user'])->get();
```

Credits to @Teun